# How to Create a RAR File in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, winrar

To create a `.rar` archive/file, we need to download WinRar first. So WinRar is available in my system but I am unable to archive my files.

I did just right-click on the file I want to compress and click on Add to archive:

[image: Adding file to archive]

After that I am unable to archive my files, Add to archive link is not working.

Comment: do you get any error message? have you tried reinstalling WinRAR?

Comment: No there is no error message & I also tried after reinstalling WinRar.

Comment: can you manually start WinRAR from start menu?

Comment: HOW does it not work?

Comment: What happens when you press ``Add to archive...``? Do you get any message on the screen? Are you using the original WinRar with a license or pirated one?

Comment: What happens if you select `Add to "Wind8apps.rar"`?

Comment: What version of winrar?

Comment: @alljamin Not getting any message..

Comment: @Moab Version: WinRAR x86 (32 bit) 5.31

Comment: @Kusum so during the workflow, when you press ``Add to archive ...`` nothing happens? Can you start WinRAR manually as @Divin3 suggested? You should either add more screenshots or workflow information, not just say _this is not working_.

Comment: @Kusum darn, I don't have that version to test on W10, sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've heard before about issues with winrar and windows 10.

Some people say it's not completely supported which is why it can have issues, I'm not 100% sure though as i do not use winrar.

An alternative is 7zip, which is what i use regularly.

http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

I prefer it to Winrar as there isn't a pop up when you open it and it seems faster.

Just personal opinion though.